# How to randomise treatments in five blocks using Rstudio without a treatment being repeated?

Tags: r, experimental-design, heap-randomization

In the orchard experiment, there are 5 treatments and 5 blocks. To allow for analysis of the effects of the treatments on tree and fruit growth the treatments are the same on either side of the middle tree row. How can I randomise the treatments in R without having the last treatment of a block being the same as the starting treatment of the next block. For example, I have used  the agricolae package to randomise the treatments within their blocks but I get randomisation such as this:

```
Block 1: 3 1 5 2 4 
Block 2: 2 3 4 5 1
Block 3: 2 5 1 4 3 
Block 4: 1 5 3 4 2
Block 5: 2 3 1 5 4
```

As you can see block 4 finishes with treatment 2 and then block 5 starts with 2. I would like to avoid this if possible but I am not sure how to do it in r.

A visual representation of the experiment with the treatments not randomised within their plots:

[image: The image is a visual representation of the experiment with the treatments not randomised within their plots]

Running the solution below, I come across the issue of the new table not showing numbers.

[Print screen of the command dput(head(data,20))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHvGF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you had data that looked like this:

```
head(data,10)
#     Block TreeMiddleRow
#1  Block 1   Treatment 1
#2  Block 1   Treatment 2
#3  Block 1   Treatment 3
#4  Block 1   Treatment 4
#5  Block 1   Treatment 5
#6  Block 2   Treatment 1
#7  Block 2   Treatment 2
#8  Block 2   Treatment 3
#9  Block 2   Treatment 4
#10 Block 2   Treatment 5
```

You could use a `while` loop to continue resampling by group until none of the block boundaries equaled each other:

```
treatments <- rep("Tretment",nrow(data))
while(any(treatments[head(cumsum(rle(data$Block)$lengths),-1)] == treatments[head(cumsum(rle(data$Block)$lengths),-1)+1])){
  treatments <<- unname(unlist(tapply(data$TreeMiddleRow,
                                      data$Block,
                                      FUN = function(x) sample(x,size = 5, replace = FALSE))))
}
data$TreeMiddleRow <- treatments
head(data,10)
#     Block TreeMiddleRow
#1  Block 1   Treatment 2
#2  Block 1   Treatment 3
#3  Block 1   Treatment 4
#4  Block 1   Treatment 5
#5  Block 1   Treatment 1
#6  Block 2   Treatment 2
#7  Block 2   Treatment 5
#8  Block 2   Treatment 3
#9  Block 2   Treatment 4
#10 Block 2   Treatment 1
```

Note that `cumsum` with `rle` allows us to return the indices of boundaries between blocks. `head(x,-1)` removes the last one because we don't care about it:

```
head(cumsum(rle(data$Block)$lengths),-1)
#[1]  5 10 15 20
```

Sample Data:

```
data <- data.frame(Block = rep(paste("Block",1:5),each = 5),
                   TreeMiddleRow = rep(paste("Treatment",1:5),times = 5))
```

Comment: Hello, again Ian. I am trying to rerun the code but the while loop does not show the randomized treatment numbers, only the word Treatment. Any ideas?

Comment: treatments <- rep("Treatment",nrow(data))
while(any(treatments[head(cumsum(rle(data$Block)$lengths),-1)] == treatments[head(cumsum(rle(data$Block)$lengths),-1)+1])){
      treatments <<- unname(unlist(tapply(data$TreeMiddleRow,
                                      data$Block,
                                      FUN = function(x) sample(x,size = 5, replace = FALSE))))
}

data$TreeMiddleRow <- treatments

head(data,10)

Comment: Take a look at [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td3xA.png). Perhaps it will help you find the issue?

Comment: Thank you Ian! It works on the online terminal. I will uninstall Rstudio on my laptop and reinstall it. I hope it resolves the issue. Thank you again